# Dart: argument type "List<Section>" can't be assigned to the parameter type "List<Section>?"

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I have a copywith method I'm trying to use like this in a qubit...

```
final sections = await getSections(_database.getInstance(), _projectID, zoneID);
emit(state.copyWith(sections:sections));
```

And I keep getting an assignment error but when I do the exact same thing for zones I don't get the same error. The below cod works fine.

```
final zones = await getZones(_database.getInstance(), _projectID);
emit(state.copyWith(zones:zones));
```

getSections will either return a list of sections or an empty list if none are found.

```
class SearchBySectionState extends Equatable {

  final Zone? zone;
  final List<Zone> zones;
  final Section? section;
  final List<Section> sections;

  const SearchBySectionState._({
    this.zones = const <Zone>[],
    this.zone,
    this.sections = const <Section>[],
    this.section
  });

  const SearchBySectionState.initial() : this._();

  const SearchBySectionState.zoneLoadSuccess({ required List<Zone> zones}) : this._(zones: zones);


  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [zones, zone, sections, section ];

  SearchBySectionState copyWith({
    List<Zone>? zones,
    Zone? zone,
    List<Section>? sections,
    Section? section
  }) {
    return SearchBySectionState._(
      zone: zone ?? this.zone,
      zones: zones ?? this.zones,
      section: section ?? this.section,
      sections: sections ?? this.sections
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't you be able to sign a guaranteed non-nullable to a nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue was incredibly stupid. In my loadSections code I imported Section model class from ../Section.dart. But really it should have been ../section.dart. Apparently Vscode doesn't warning you about case sensitivity. -_-